# How do I create a user using a post request in react-chat-engine?

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-chat-engine

I am looking to add a Registration feature to my application that uses react-chat-engine but it's failing with a 403 error.

```
Error: Request failed with status code 403
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onloadend (xhr.js:66)
```

A user should be able to sign up, fill in their details and get logged in with this feature. I found a similar issue here [how to make a post request to create new users in react-chat-engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67394361/how-to-make-a-post-request-to-create-new-users-in-react-chat-engine) but the solution does not work for me and I don't have the reputation to comment ;).

My code:

```
const SignupForm = () => {
    

    const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    const [firstname, setFirst] = useState('');
    const [lastname, setLast] = useState('');
    const [error, setError] = useState('');

    // function to handle the submit
    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        //header for authentication
        const authObject = {'Private-Key': '4922e43b-xxxxx-xxxx'}
        
        // post request to create user
        try {
            await axios.post('https://api.chatengine.io/users/',
            { headers: authObject,
             body: {
                'username': username,
                'secret': password
                }
            });
            // login the user
            localStorage.setItem('username', username)
            localStorage.setItem('password', password)

            window.location.reload()
         } catch (error) {
             console.log(error)
             setError('Incorrect credentials, try again')
         }
                            
    }
```

I have intentionally blurred out parts of my private key for obvious reasons. My Private key is valid, I have copied it directly from the dashboard. Also, I am able to add a user manually in the dashboard

What could I be missing?

Comment: Private-Key needs to be write in upper case. https://rest.chatengine.io/#6775ec07-601e-4730-ba08-d87bc81d019a users section.

Comment: This makes no difference, I have tried a couple of times. Also, from the question I referenced above, the accepted solution is in lowercase so this can't be the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should be two separate objects for Body and Headers

```
axios.post(
  "https://api.chatengine.io/users/",
  {'username': username, 'secret': password}, // Body object
  {'headers': authObject} // Headers object
)
.then(r => console.log(r))
```

Comment: Yes, this works perfectly! Thank you, Adam!